# How to get a response from localhost server in GWT client side?

Tags: java, url, gwt, http-response-codes

I have a `WCF` based web service and hosted on local machine written in `c#`. I want to get a response from this hosted service in my `GWT client side`.

Please check the following code:

```
url = "localhost:8089/request"
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
Request response = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {
   @override
   public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
       Window.alert(response + " ");
     }
 });
```

Everytime when i am trying to run the code it shows an "`http://localhost:8089 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.`"

PS: i searched for this error but i don't want to disable the web security of all browsers.

Is there any alternative solution to do get `response` of `localhost` server running on different porn on same machine. That is why i want to call a url in client side.

Please suggest a solution.

### Edit

Let me explain you full scenario in points:

```
GWT application is hosted on some server (www.abc.com)
WCF is a web service installed at each client.
A client open his/her browser and put the url (www.abc.com/page)
This page want to access the web services hosted on a client machine.
```

Comment: How will your app be deployed? Will the GWT app be served at the same origin as the WCF service? (I'm trying to understand whether it's a problem you'll have only at dev time, or a more global issue with what you're trying to build)

Comment: Gwt application is hosted on my locahost server as well as my Windows applicaiton.

yes i am on dev side

Comment: Oh sorry! yes it will use the same origin of WCF service which resides on "localhost" url and app will be deployed on a global server

Comment: @ThomasBroyer please see the edit section

Answer (score 1):

Can't you configure your WCF service to send an `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: www.abc.com` response header?

Otherwise, I guess you could use a [*proxy servlet*](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=3131) in `www.abc.com` that proxies the call to the [`getRemoteAddr`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRemoteAddr%28%29), assuming there's no proxy in-between.

Comment: I also tried to add <customHeaders>
        <add name ="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      </customHeaders> in appconfig file